# Infoset query SELECT SUM issue

Tags: select, sum, abap

I am trying to sum all quantities (MENGE) lines where PO number (EBELN) AND item number in the corresponding PO (EBELP) and Movement type (BWART) "101" then subtract an equivalent table with Movement type "102" to get the final quantity as the result.

Currently I added 2 custom fields, one for 101 and one for 102 movement, to break it down and see the results. With my current code, the report shows the correct data for 101 column, but returns a lot of rubbish for 102: it has the correct data, but it returns numbers/data where there should be none and I can't figure out why or where is it pulling the numbers from.

The code below:

*DATA TAB

```
DATA: itab1 like table of mseg,
       wa1 like mseg,
       wa2 like mseg. 
DATA: *mseg like table of mseg. 
DATA: itab3 like table of ekbe,
       wa3 like ekbe. 
Data: *ekbe like table of ekbe. 
data: QNT101_menge like mseg-menge,
       QNT102_menge like mseg-menge,
       QNT103_MENGE LIKE EKBE-MENGE.`
```

*Record Processing TAB

```
if sy-subrc eq 0.   
wa1-ebeln = mseg-ebeln.   
wa1-menge = mseg-menge. 
wa1-ebelp = mseg-ebelp.   
wa1-bwart = mseg-bwart.   
wa2-ebeln = mseg-ebeln.   
wa2-ebelp = mseg-ebelp.   
wa2-menge = mseg-menge.  
wa2-bwart = mseg-bwart.   
Select: sum( menge ) as menge into QNT101_menge   
   from mseg 
   where ebeln = wa1-ebeln    
     and ebelp = wa1-ebelp 
     and bwart = 101 
   group by ebeln ebelp.
endselect. 
clear *mseg.   
Select sum( menge ) as menge into QNT102_menge    
  from mseg
  where ebeln = wa1-ebeln
    and ebelp = wa1-ebelp
    and bwart = 102
  group by ebeln ebelp.   
endselect. 
append wa1 to itab1.    
clear wa1. 
endif.
```

And my custom fields only have some basic code like

```
ACTUALQNT2 = QNT102_MENGE.
```

There are more variables than I use, because I plan on building the report further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the select statements.

You're accessing `MSEG` with single values of `EBELN` and `EBELP` at a time, taken the values from `wa1` structure and using an aggregate sum.

You don't need to `group by`, since you are not accessing with multiple EBELN, EBELP values.

Also the `ENDSELECT` statement produces a sort of "loop" in MSEG DB table that is not needed.

Try using the following:

```
Select sum( menge ) as menge into QNT101_menge
 from mseg
where ebeln = wa1-ebeln
  and ebelp = wa1-ebelp
  and bwart = '101'.

Select sum( menge ) as menge into QNT102_menge
  from mseg
 where ebeln = wa1-ebeln
   and ebelp = wa1-ebelp
   and bwart = '102'.
```

Also for performance reasons you should try to not access DB when not needed (you were selecting twice with almost the same criteria).

Here's a better version

Gets a table of quantities summed by movement type (101 or 102)

```
select bwart, sum( menge ) as menge
  from mseg
  into table @data(lt_quantity)
 where ebeln = @wa1-ebeln
   and ebelp = @wa1-ebelp
   and bwart in ( '101' , '102' )
  group by bwart.
```

Then reads from internal table the values you want. (here the `optional` is needed to avoid an execption if the mov.type is not present)

```
  qnt101_menge = value #( lt_quantity[ bwart = '101']-menge optional ).
  qnt102_menge = value #( lt_quantity[ bwart = '102']-menge optional ).
```

**EDIT: inline declarations**

starting from ABAP 7.40 you can use inline declaration directly into the `SELECT` statement. (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapinto_clause.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_5@5@))

Table `lt_quantity` is declared on the fly, in the moment the select statement is performed. You don't need to declare the table before, but instead the system creates it with the proper structure dynamically.

To use those new functionalities you must use the `@` symbol before every variable used (so also when using `@wa1`)

If your system version does not support this syntax yet, here's the classic version of the statement. Please note the classic `SELECT` syntax also differs from the new one (no commas between fields, no `@`, `INTO` part declared at the bottom of the statement)

```
types: begin of qty_type,
  bwart type mseg-bwart,
  menge type mseg-menge,
  end of qty_type.

data: lt_quantity type table of qty_type.

select bwart sum( menge ) as menge
  from mseg
  into table lt_quantity
 where ebeln = wa1-ebeln
   and ebelp = wa1-ebelp
   and bwart in ( '101' , '102' )
 group by bwart.
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this ver useful comment. I just want to understand. Can you elaborate on `into table @data(lt_quantity)` statement? And  `@` 's function in your code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've added a quick explanation regarding the syntax available starting from ABAP 7.40.

Comment: Yeah, I believe we are still on 7.02 so that's why your code didn't work for me. This was very helpful information nontheless. Just one last quick question. In terms of performance and assuming the result is the same - would it be more effecient to add/use via the code section or drop it directly in to the custom fields with something like this: `select sum( menge ) as menge
   from *mseg into ACTQNT
  where *mseg~ebeln eq mseg-ebeln
  and *mseg~ebelp eq mseg-ebelp
  and *mseg~bwart = '101'.` As the report will grow in volume I'd like to make it as simple/efficient as possible. thanks.

Comment: from a performance point of view it doesn't make a lot of difference if you use `SELECT .. into ACTQNT` or `SELECT .. into TEMP.` and then  `ACTQNT = TEMP`